# Date Range wildcard

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so I have these xml files that have date ranges on them. Heres an example:

```
System.IO.File.Move(files[i], "C:\\Checks\\XMLFiles\\" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-hhmmssfff") + ".xml");
```

What I want to do is to format it in such a way where the NOW will be just todays date, and the hhmmssfff will be a wildcard, basically showing me everything from just today.

Any ideas here? Im a newbie so sorry if its a stupid question.

Thanks!

```
System.IO.File.Move(files[i], "C:\\Checks\\XMLFiles\\" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-") + ________ + ".xml");
```

Oh here are a couple of the file names just for reference:

> 08-24-2010-123701072 
>   08-24-2010-124852164 
>   08-24-2010-123715462 
>   08-24-2010-123348784 
>   08-23-2010-124607792

Below is my orginal code:

> protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>          {
>              {
>                  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
>                  Response.Charset = "";
>                  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>                  ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("checks.xml"));
>                  XmlDataDocument xdd = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
>                  XslTransform xt = new XslTransform();
>                  xt.Load(Server.MapPath("WellsFargoFile.xsl"));
>                  xt.Transform(xdd, null, Response.OutputStream);
>                                  Response.End();
>              }

I want to remove checks.xml and insert something that has some sort of date range, just minus the hours seconds, etc. So the code that I found would work.

Comment: 'C:/Checks/XMLFiles/08-24-2010-*.xml' is a physical path, but a > virtual path was expected. This is the error I get when I format it like such:  ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("C:/Checks/XMLFiles/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-*") + ".xml"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just omit the hhmmssfff portion and and leave it as the date only?

```
System.IO.File.Move(files[i], @"C:\Checks\XMLFiles\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-") + ".xml");
```

Comment: B/C I get an error: 
'C:/Checks/XMLFiles/08-24-2010-.xml' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Comment: Are you running this from within a web application?  Is there some Server.MapPath code that you've left out?

Comment: ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("C:\\Checks\\XMLFiles\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "/*" +".xml"));

Comment: Or this: 
 ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Checks\XMLFiles\", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-*.xml")));

Comment: Eliminate the Server.MapPath and it should work, assuming your user has access to that folder.

Comment: Ive removed it but I seem to still be getting an error. This is what I have:           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Checks\XMLFiles\", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-*.xml"));
                XmlDataDocument xdd = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
                XslTransform xt = new XslTransform();
                xt.Load(Server.MapPath("WellsFargoFile.xsl"));
                xt.Transform(xdd, null, Response.OutputStream);
                Response.End();

Comment: Can you post that code (and any more if you have it) to your original post so it can be formatted and easier to read?

Comment: OK Steve I just loaded the code for the button that Ive been using. Ive been tasked to point it to a folder with a group of xml files and pick out the one for each day. Also, there may be several xml files for each day as well.

Comment: Hey Steve, 

It still throws this message: 
'C:/Checks/XMLFiles/08-25-2010/*.xml' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Comment: IM trying to go straight to the server here: 

> ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(("\\192.168.1.132//Checks//XMLFiles//" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "*" +".xml")));

Comment: Yeah, you need to get rid of that Server.MapPath as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like the Directory.GetFiles method that takes a wildcard:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Checks\XMLFiles\", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-*.xml"))
```

That will get the list of all files in the directory for that given day, then you can loop through the return of that calling File.Move on each of those.